# What are the differences between frame attributes box and border in html tables

Tags: html, html-table, border, frame

I'm taking some classes on Web Programming and no one in the class including the instructor can say what the difference is between the frame values box and border when it comes to html tables. Here is an example of what I am talking about.

```
<table frame="border">
<!-- some basic table data -->
</table>

<table frame="box">
<!-- some basic table data -->
</table>
```

These two tables as far as I can tell will render the same way as one another. Are there any underlying differences that may not be apparent at first or is there a right or wrong way to use them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference; they're aliases of each other. From the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.3.1):

> This attribute specifies which sides of the frame surrounding a table will be visible. Possible values:
>
> - ...
> - `box:` All four sides.
> - `border:` All four sides.

Today, pretty much the only right way to use them is to *not* use them. Table border styles should be defined using CSS instead of presentational attributes, of which `frame` is an example, albeit a rather obscure one. Browser support for this attribute [seems quite patchy](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/table/frame#compatibilitysection) anyway, again owing to its obscurity.

Answer (score 1):

box     The outside borders are shown on all four sides

border  The outside borders are shown on all four sides

i.e. they are the same
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_frame.asp

Comment: You should note, also, that this is deprecated functionality now. CSS is the preferred method, as referenced in the article linked here. The  `frame=` attribute is no longer supported as-of HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been stated they do the same thing, and you shouldn't be using the frame attribute anyway.

To understand why there were two different values for the same thing, it's necessary to read [RFC 1942 HTML Tables](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1942.txt) which says:

> The value "Border" is included for backwards compatibility with
>   deployed browsers. If a document includes `<TABLE BORDER>` the user
>   agent will see FRAME=BORDER and BORDER=*implied*. If the document
>   includes `<TABLE BORDER=_n_>` then the user agent should treat this as
>   FRAME=BORDER except if *n=0* for which FRAME=VOID is appropriate.
>
> Note: it would have been preferable to choose values for FRAME
>   consistent with the RULES attribute and the values used for alignment.
>   For instance: none, top, bottom, topbot, left, right, leftright, all.
>   Unfortunately, SGML requires enumerated attribute values to be unique
>   for each element, independent of the attribute name. This causes
>   immediate problems for "none", "left", "right" and "all". The values
>   for FRAME have been chosen to avoid clashes with the RULES, ALIGN and
>   VALIGN attributes. This provides a measure of future proofing, as it
>   is anticipated that that the FRAME and RULES attributes will be added
>   to other table elements in future revisions to this specification. An
>   alternative would be to make FRAME a CDATA attribute. The consensus of
>   the HTML-WG was that the benefits of being able to use SGML validation
>   tools to check attributes based on enumerated values outweighs the
>   need for consistent names.

So "border" was already in use by browsers before the spec was written but wasn't compatible with a subtlety of SGML, so "box" was added to provide an SGML compatible way of doing the same thing.

Because browsers don't actually follow SGML rules, it's not easy to see an effect of the above, but the pre-HTML5 validators did, and it is possible to see a small effect. Consider this markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
                 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<title>Test</title>
<table border border=5>
<tr><td>Test</td></tr>
</table>
```

Normally having two attributes with the same name will cause an error to be reported by the validator, but try this at the W3C HTML validator and you will see that it passes validation. That because the validator sees the first `border` attribute as a short form of `frame="border"` and so there's no name collision.

Browsers, on the other hand, do see a name collision and will ignore the `border=5` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

They are the nearly same, but since they are different in name context they are depended on different browser supports.

frame means that there should be all four borders, while box is the same but it can be used with rules. like this: rules="none"